# UIViewController presented with .OverCurrentContext is opaque with .CrossDissolve

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, overlay

I am trying to get the familiar "translucent overlay" effect. I am using the .OverCurrentContext presentation style, and the presented VC has a view with 0.5 alpha, set in storyboard.

When I use the (default) transition of .CoverVertical, all is good. When I use .CrossDissolve (which is what I want) the presented view is opaque. When I check the presented view's alpha, it has somehow become 1. Why? Where do I intercede to prevent this?

```
let vc = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Overlay")!
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .OverCurrentContext
vc.modalTransitionStyle = .CrossDissolve
self.presentViewController(vc, animated:true, completion:nil)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Where do I intercede to prevent this?

You intercede in the *whole* animation. You're going to have to do a custom transition animation for your view controller presentation, because what you want to do is not covered by any of the four or five standard animations.

Comment: I don't really want the blur effect. Or at least, don't need it. A plain translucent overlay will be fine. To repeat, I get the correct overlay effect with the .CoverVertical transition, but the .CrossDissolve transition seems to itself be fiddling with the alpha.

Now, a workaround *almost* is to set the alpha of the overlay to 1 but setting the background color to have a fractional opacity. Now I do dissolve to the translucent overlay. But there is still an annoying flash in the transition.

Comment: Of course .CrossDissolve fiddles with the alpha. That is _what_ it does. It does a cross dissolve! What I said is still correct: you will need to do a custom transition animation, so that _you_ are in charge of the alpha throughout the transition. It isn't hard, you know.

Comment: Your essentialist critique of .CrossDissolve is correct. As is the rest of your answer. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it is possible with custom transitions: the presentED view should have an alpha of 1 but the background color has a fractional alpha. Then all is fine. However... I notice that if I use a custom transition (nicely explained in your book!)  I need to set modalPresentationStyle to .Custom. That seems to negate the desired overlay effect. Can I still arrange to see through to the presentING VC?

Comment: It's your VC; you can do whatever you like with it. If you tell its view to have a less-than-zero alpha, it does. Or at least that's what I would have expected. That's not the case?

Comment: I really don't know what you mean about "negates the overlay effect". You can have any effect you want. You are in total charge.

Comment: Look at the first screen shot in the Presented View Controllers section of my book. That shows you a presented view controller thru which you can see, blurred, the presenting view controller.

Comment: Here's what I meant. Using .OverCurrentContext means "The views beneath the presented content are not removed from the view hierarchy when the presentation finishes." If I have to use .Custom, I *thought*  the underlying views would be removed, and even with fractional alpha, I wouldn't see the presentING VC. (Haven't tried it because I went with adding an overlying subview instead. That way I don't cover up the NavBar.) However, the screen shot you mentioned does seem to imply otherwise.

Comment: "If I have to use .Custom, I thought the underlying views would be removed" You are in charge. More specifically, the presentation controller's `shouldRemovePresentersView` governs this, and it is `false` by default. (That's what my book says, and I believe the Me who wrote it until proven otherwise.) So if you just do nothing, they _won't_ be removed.

Comment: Do you need a working example? https://github.com/mattneub/custom-alert-view-iOS7 You'll notice that the underlying view is definitely not removed, and yet I didn't do anything special.